# Styles not loading when accessing application hosted on localhost AMPPS from an external device

Tags: php, css, macos, styles, ampps

I've installed an instance of Zenbership on my localhost AMPPS and it seems to load properly when on the localhost. However when I tried to access it from an external device (such as another PC or tablet) the styles don't seem load; just the content.

Is there any setting I need to change?

Comment: can you check in devtools console or network tab - any errors there? where the app is trying to get styles from?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry Thanks for the suggestion. I looked into the Console and Network tabs. It seems its trying to get the css from the localhost even though it's been accessed from another machine (i.e. request URL is http://localhost/zenbership/pp-templates/html/zoid/css/primary.css).  However I access the application using http://172.20.4.51/zenbership. Could you help me sort this out?

Comment: I am not familiar with ampps, but can you post the code that refers to style sheet?